# Thawed frozen fresh strawberries, can i refreeze them

Tags: food-safety

I left fresh strawberries, which I cleaned and froze, on the counter to thaw for 5 hrs by mistake. They mostly thawed. I want to know if I can refreeze them. I use them to blend them up in a meal replacement shake. They are less than a week old.

Comment: You pulled them from the freezer to use them, right?  Why not just put then in fridge and use them when you make the shake?

Answer (score 2):

**Refreeze them if you aren't using right away**

Your strawberries started out well below freezing point of water. Home freezers operate at close to 0 F. Cooling is a function of temperature difference between substance and surroundings. Your strawberries are in no danger, unless they were absolutely covered in bacteria before freezing, like you had rubbed rotten halibut on them for some reason.

Any texture will be changed with freezing and blending, so don't worry about that.

I like frozen fruit in smoothies, as it gives thick texture without ice addition.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm concerned if it was left out for more than 2 hours in room temperature you have the chance of it growing bacteria. You can freeze them again but to kill those bacteria you'll have to cook them which will make them taste terrible. If I was you, I would eat one or split it in the middle to see how bad they really are. Otherwise you can put them in the fridge and keep them there until you would like to use them.

Comment: Frozen strawberries left out for two hours probably spent most of that time well below 40 degrees F.  The issue is the time spent thawed. Secondly, cooked strawberries can be delicious, but that is a matter of opinion.  Finally, what would splitting one allow you to see?  It would look like a thawed, fresh strawberry, no?  You would certainly not be able to see if they were growing bacteria.

Comment: You could see if there is mold forming inside or the texture of the strawberry. The bacteria grows from the inside out. I might be wrong about it, but just to be safe I would not eat it or serve it to a customer or a family member

Comment: I think you may be confused between bacteria and mold, both of which would begin on the outside of the strawberry, if bacteria or mold spores were present...not on the inside.  Also, there is no way you would see bacteria growth with the naked eye in the span of 5 hours.  Finally, you can probably imagine the texture of a thawed strawberry.  It alone will tell you nothing about safety.

Comment: You are right, I need to retake my test again lol. But none the less I wouldnt serve them to no one neither eat them myself. Just for your safety and everyone else around you throw them out and buy new ones. You are only supposed to thaw out food for a spam of two hours if it goes more than that and it hasnt reach the temperature required for that food its bad. According to the food manager classes i took.